# Unknown type name 'class' when include C++ code in Cocoa/Objective-C project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

So, basically this it (I think I have solved it in the past somehow, but I canNOT remember HOW...) :

- I've got a - pretty much empty - Objective-C/Cocoa project
- Import some .c/.cpp files
- Get the following error

> Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just renamed my `.cpp` files to `.mm`. :-)

That did the trick!